# In KMM Compose, how to implement call backs between shared module and native iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I want to able to call a method of native iOS from shared module and do platform specific things in the background, by doing so I also want to get back a result. Here is my current code.

I've tried the following:

```
@Composable
fun App(callBack: () -> Unit) {

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceAround
    ) {
        var counter by remember { mutableIntStateOf(0) }

        Button(
            onClick = {
                counter++
            }
        ) {
            Text("Click Me")
            callBack.invoke()
        }

        Text("Counter : $counter")

        android.util.Log.d(
            "TAG",
            "ProcessData result : ${processData("Hello from : ${getPlatform()}")}"
        )

    }

}
```

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI
import shared

struct ComposeView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIViewController {
        return Main_iosKt.MainViewController(callBack:myCallback)
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: Context) {}
    
}

let myCallback: @convention(block) () -> Void = {
    // Handle the callback in your iOS code
    print("Callback from Compose UI")
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    init(){
        
    }

    var body: some View {
        ComposeView()
                .ignoresSafeArea(.all, edges: .bottom) // Compose has own keyboard handler
    }
}
```

I know that in this cases, we have to use expect/actual, but it is not calling native iOS side code from shared module. Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: You're invoking callback in wrong place. Call callback in onClick.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to use `expect` / `actual` approach in this case. Your code is absolutely correct.

If you want to get back result, you need to change `callBack` type to `() -> SomeResult`.

All you need to do is to make `myCallback` in swift part return `SomeResult` instance.

Also you can use DI containers (such as [Koin](https://insert-koin.io/docs/reference/koin-mp/kmp)) for this purpose.

In that case you can create Kotlin interface, e.g. `BackgroundJobsService` and make platform specific implementation for Android and iOS. You can modify Koin's get started to pass it into your `HelperKt.doInitKoin()` method, this way:

```kotlin
// Helper.kt

fun initKoin(backgroundJobService: BackgroundJobService) {
    val appModule = module {
           singleOf { backgroundJobService }
    }

    startKoin {
        modules(appModule)
    }
}
```

and in Swift this interface will be automatically transformed into Swift protocol, you just need to implement it.

```swift
class IosBackgroundJobsService: BackgroundJobsService {
  // class definition goes here
}


@main
struct iOSApp: App {
    
    // Koin Call
    init() {
        HelperKt.doInitKoin(IosBackgroundJobsService())
    }
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

After that you can inject your `BackgroundJobService` anywhere in your app.